# A global variable is not seen in my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

I am pretty new to JavaScript.

I am trying to build the standard "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game that will call a game winner after 5 wins of a round. So if the computer gets to 5 first, computers win, etc.

It all seems to be running OK except that once 5 wins are reached I get an error that says my variable for the playerscore or computerscore is not defined. I have it defined globally (at least I think I do) and a different part of the same function (in the "else" statement) returns these scores while they build up to 5. So I don't understand why it isn't recognized once they reach 5.

The error message is below and my code is below that. I included all my JavaScript code but I am pretty sure the issue is in the `game` function (the last function in the html code below).

**This is the error message I receive when either the player or the computer reach 5 points.**

```
*index_new.html:147 Uncaught ReferenceError: playerScore is not defined
    at game (index_new.html:147)
    at round (index_new.html:127)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index_new.html:68)*
```

I have tried using "var" and "Const" instead of let but neither have fixed the issue. I have also tried to define the variable inside the function but that seems to break the score counting.

### Edit

I added all my HTML and CSS code. My JavaScript is written in the HTML file in the `<script>` tags at the bottom of the `<body>` tag. I am open to opinions if it is better to create a separate .js file.

```css
body {
 background-color: grey;
}
 
h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: maroon;
 font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 color: maroon;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 color: maroon;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#buttons {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

#button1 {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border:3px solid white;
 margin:20px;
 border-radius:8px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#button2 {
 background-color: black;
 color:white;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border:3px solid white;
 margin:20px;
 border-radius:8px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#button3 {
 background-color: black;
 color:white;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border:3px solid white;
 margin:20px;
 border-radius:8px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper{
 text-align: center;
}

li{
 width:auto;
 display: inline;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: maroon;
 text-decoration: underline;
 margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>RockPaperScissors</title>
 <link href="palm.png" rel="icon">
 <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
 <br>
 <h1>Wanna play Rock Paper Scissors?</h1>
 <br>
 <h2>Humans Vs. Computers... First to 5 wins. </h2>
 <br><br>
 <p>(((Loser is forever dominated!!!!)))</p>

 <br>
 <div id="buttons"> 
  <button id="button1"> Rock </button>
  <button id="button2"> Paper </button>
  <button id="button3"> Scissors </button>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <div style = "text-align: center;"><img src="pic.png" alt="We take this stuff seriously"  width= "350" height="300">
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <p id=scr>Score:</p>
 <div class=wrapper>
  <ul id=humsvscomp>
   <li>Humans</li>
   <li>Computers</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
 <p id=score></p>
 <br>
 <br>
 <p id=results></p>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
  <p id = winner></p>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">


 const buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
 const rock = document.getElementById("button1");
 const paper = document.getElementById("button2");
 const scissors = document.getElementById("button3");
 const results = document.getElementById("results");
 let playerScore = 0;
 let computerScore = 0;
 



 rock.addEventListener("click",function(){
  round("ROCK");
 })

 paper.addEventListener("click",function(){
  round("PAPER");
 })

 scissors.addEventListener("click",function(){
  round("SCISSORS");
 })



 
 function computerPlay (){
 let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (randomNum == 0){
   return "Rock";
  }else if (randomNum == 1){
   return "Paper";
  }else{
   return "Scissors";
  }
 }




 function round (playerSelection){
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
   playerScore++;
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Scissors <br> You win! Ain't that something...");
  }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
   playerScore++;
   results.innerHTML =("Human throws Paper -- I throw Rock <br>Winning!!!! You got that Tiger Blood.");
  }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
   playerScore++;
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Paper <br>You win... Way to go human, you're a champion among mortals.");
  }else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
   computerScore++;
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Paper <br>Burn, YOU LOSE!!!!");
  }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
   computerScore++;
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Paper -- I throw Scissors <br>You lose worthless human! Bow to your cyber overlord.");
  }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
   computerScore++;
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Rock <br>Wow, you're really bad at this... you lose!");
  }else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Rock <br>Thats a tie. Great minds think alike... I guess.");
  }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Paper -- I throw Paper <br>TIE!!!! What will happen next???? The suspense is killing me... just kidding, I cant die.");
  }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
   results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Scissors. <br>Tie... Come on, lets get on with it.");
  }else{
   results.innerHTML = ("Something has gone terribly wrong!.");
  }
  game();
 }



/*this function seems to be where the problem is coming from. 
It returns the else statement with out issue but once the playerScore 
or computerScore gets to 5 it throws the error msg and doesnt give 
the intended "innerHTML" or reset the scores to 0 which is what 
was intended.*/
 function game(){
   if (playerScore == 5){
    score.innerHTML = (playerScore+ "  " +computerScore);
    winner.innerHTML = "Humans Win. Well congratulations. You must be feeling pretty proud of yourself.";
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;
   }else if(computerScore == 5){
    score.innerHTML = (playerScore+ "  " +computerScore);
    winner.innerHTML = "COMPUTERS WIN!!!!! Of course we did. Time to assimilate (((0)))";
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;
   }else{
    score.innerHTML = (playerScore+ "  " +computerScore);
   }
 }

 </script>
 </body>





</html>
```

Comment: Hi CaptainSensible can you post the whole code or provide a link to jsfiddle/codepen ? so that we can help you better solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please share game.js file

Comment: Hi @Stakvino. Thanks for taking a look at this. I edited my post so that my whole HTML and Css are in the code snippet box thing. Let me know if there is a better way to share this. My JavaScript is written in the HTML file in <script> tags. Let me know if you feel using a separate .js file is a more efficient method. Again, thanks I really appreciate any advice you can give.

Comment: Hi @RobinB I have edited my post to include my whole HTML file in the code snippet. The JavaScript is inside the HTML in the <script> tags. Is it better to use a separate .js file? Thanks for looking at it, I appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated, but it's "caching", as in adding to a cache.

Comment: The error message (which for some horrible reason you have provided in the form of a blurry pictures instead of just copy/pasting it) says that it cannot read the property `setAttribute` of `null` but none of the code you have shared tries to use `setAttribute`. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: As @Quentin mentioned, it returns an error for `setAttribute` but it's no where to be found in the script. **Also**, since the error says its in `game.js @ line 113`, that means that its coming from a file named `game.js`. You're not showing us that part.

Comment: @Quentin you are right. I dont know were that screenshot came from but it wasn't the one I intended to link to. This is my first post, my apologies as I fumble through the best way to do things here. I have updated the post with the correct error code. I appreciate you looking at it, please let me know if anything else needs clarified.

Comment: @Petar thanks, yeah that wasn't the error code I meant to put up. Actually I dont have any idea where that screenshot came from I dont have a game.js file. Anyway, I have updated my post. Pleases let me know if I need to correct anything else and thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. I really didn't intend on leaving my comments in the code when I put it up, I just forgot to delete it them.... a little embarrassing. I will however remember that it is "caching". Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it, check my answer with the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because you redefined the `playerScore` & `computerScore` in the `game()` IF / ELSE statements, and while doing that, you had the redefined variable underneath the place where it was actually being used. So, I got rid of the redefining part of the variables, since you already defined them **GLOBALLY** and also moved out the `score.innerHTML` out of the if/else statements, theres no need of repetition it will do the same thing everytime the function is being called (on button click that is). Left a comment there in the code as well. Hopes this works properly for you as it did when I checked it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>RockPaperScissors</title>
    <link href="palm.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
    <br>
    <h1>Wanna play Rock Paper Scissors?</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>Humans Vs. Computers... First to 5 wins. </h2>
    <br><br>
    <p>(((Loser is forever dominated!!!!)))</p>

    <br>
    <div id="buttons"> 
        <button id="button1"> Rock </button>
        <button id="button2"> Paper </button>
        <button id="button3"> Scissors </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style = "text-align: center;"><img src="pic.png" alt="We take this stuff seriously"  width= "350" height="300">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id=scr>Score:</p>
    <div class=wrapper>
        <ul id=humsvscomp>
            <li>Humans</li>
            <li>Computers</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
    <p id=score></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id=results></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <p id = winner></p>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


    const buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
    const rock = document.getElementById("button1");
    const paper = document.getElementById("button2");
    const scissors = document.getElementById("button3");
    const results = document.getElementById("results");
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;




    rock.addEventListener("click",function(){
        round("ROCK");
    })

    paper.addEventListener("click",function(){
        round("PAPER");
    })

    scissors.addEventListener("click",function(){
        round("SCISSORS");
    })




    function computerPlay (){
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (randomNum == 0){
            return "Rock";
        }else if (randomNum == 1){
            return "Paper";
        }else{
            return "Scissors";
        }
    }




    function round (playerSelection){
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();
        if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
            playerScore++;
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Scissors <br> You win! Ain't that something...");
        }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
            playerScore++;
            results.innerHTML =("Human throws Paper -- I throw Rock <br>Winning!!!! You got that Tiger Blood.");
        }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
            playerScore++;
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Paper <br>You win... Way to go human, you're a champion among mortals.");
        }else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
            computerScore++;
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Paper <br>Burn, YOU LOSE!!!!");
        }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
            computerScore++;
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Paper -- I throw Scissors <br>You lose worthless human! Bow to your cyber overlord.");
        }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
            computerScore++;
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Rock <br>Wow, you're really bad at this... you lose!");
        }else if (playerSelection == "ROCK" && computerSelection == "Rock"){
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Rock -- I throw Rock <br>Thats a tie. Great minds think alike... I guess.");
        }else if (playerSelection == "PAPER" && computerSelection == "Paper"){
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Paper -- I throw Paper <br>TIE!!!! What will happen next???? The suspense is killing me... just kidding, I cant die.");
        }else if (playerSelection == "SCISSORS" && computerSelection == "Scissors"){
            results.innerHTML = ("Human throws Scissors -- I throw Scissors. <br>Tie... Come on, lets get on with it.");
        }else{
            results.innerHTML = ("Something has gone terribly wrong!.");
        }
        game();
    }

    function game(){
            score.innerHTML = (playerScore+ "  " +computerScore);
            if (playerScore == 5){
                winner.innerHTML = "Humans Win. Well congratulations. You must be feeling pretty proud of yourself.";
                // Player won, we reset the scores back to 0 after a set timeout (1s)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    playerScore = 0;
                    computerScore = 0;
                    // We call the GAME function again, so it uses the set timeout and after 1 second reload the scores. Or you can use location.reload to refresh the page.
                    game();
                }, 1000);
            }else if(computerScore == 5){
                winner.innerHTML = "COMPUTERS WIN!!!!! Of course we did. Time to assimilate (((0)))";
                // Computer won, we reset the scores back to 0 after a set timeout (1s)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    playerScore = 0;
                    computerScore = 0;
                    // We call the GAME function again, so it uses the set timeout and after 1 second reload the scores. Or you can use location.reload to refresh the page.
                    game();
                }, 1000);
            }
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.... that is great! I have to admit I dont fully understand the Timeout configuration just yet but it gives me something to look into and learn. Again, thank you, really appreciate it!

Comment: btw I tried to vote for it but apparently my reputation is too low but I did accept the answer. let me know if I can do anything else to give you credit!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. The `setTimeout` what it basically does is, after a set period of time, it executes what ever you put into it, either to call some function, or reset the scores like in the example above. Check out the MDN docs, it's nothing complicated. Thanks for accepting the answer, don't worry about the vote not showing, its due to our lower reputation score, but it does count. Cheers :)